# Persist formik input values when the passed props to a react component changes

Tags: reactjs, render, react-props, formik, rerender

I have a child component witch gets some data passed as a prop to be used in a form handled by formik (line input options) .
when this passed props changes due to an event in another component , this child component rerender and thus the form looses the values even though we have types things in the form.

Anybody can help.
thank you

I tried to pass data to a form handled by formik as props , when this data is changed in the parent component , the form rerender and looses the value we typed in the inputs.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  It would be helpful to those that would answer your question if you could provide some code that we can use to reproduce your problem.  Showing is always better than telling!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.